# What does Eclipse project with icon "m" and exclamation mark means?

Tags: eclipse, maven, icons

I have a Maven Project in Eclipse (Version: Oxygen.3a Release - 4.7.3a). The Project folder is showing an icon with "M" and an exclamation mark. Anyone knows what does this icon mean?

[image]

I have searched through the list of icons here, but it wasn't in the list: [Eclipse JDT Icons](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm)

Comment: `M` means it is a Maven project and the red exclamation mark means that the project cannot be build because of project configuration errors (does Alt+F5 fix it?).

Answer (score 0):

That "M" indicates a Maven project. The red exclamation mark usually indicates a problem/error, often in the build path.